SSL Certificate and Cloud Run
I have a Google Cloud Function (Which exports itself into Google Cloud Run), for said Function I also have a Domain Mapping set up and this is meant to be an ODATA Service.
I also currently own said domain (Let's call it www.mysite.com), I also have a Wildcard (*.mysite.com) and SSL Certificate, all of this is currently generated and hosted by Hostinger.
Everything works perfectly fine in EXCEL and PowerBI. However when I'm trying to consume this in
I'm trying to consume this "Sap DataSphere" and I'm getting an error of it being unable to obtain the respective SSL Certificate in the Handshake.
I investigated related to this and noticed when I consume the URL I have set up in Domain Mapping in Cloud Run it generates a certificate from "Let's Encrypt", instead of using the SSL Certificate from Hostinger.
How can I force Cloud Run / Domain Mapping to use the correct SSL Certificate instead of Google generating it's own?
Thanks in advance.

You have to create a HTTPS load balancer in front of Cloud Run and load your own certificate on it
